PowerApps form changes not showing up in Dynamics 365 Customer Insights (Trial)
I've attempted to add an extra input field to my e-mail template settings in my Dynamics 365 Customer Insights (Trial). According to this document this can be done in PowerApps when you go to Components > Entities > Marketing email > Forms.
I found several of the settings screens there that I could change. But none of the changes show up in Customer Insights when creating or editing emails or email templates.
Changing the forms created an extra preferred/default solution called Common Data Services Default Solution, in which only the changes are stored.
Tried:

I added a new column in the table and form, saved and published.

Selected (and only) environment is the Trial

I've tried this with most of the forms I could find in PowerApps

Tried changing the label of an existing field, doesn't show up either


Could it be:

The environment is not managed

Not possible in Trial

Any other step that needs to be taken?


